# Java 7 on 32-bit Windows 7 - Java Webstart - Unable to load resource

Tags: java, windows-7, 32-bit, java-7, java-web-start

Java 7 on 32-bit Windows 7 - Java Webstart - Unable to load resource

I can't launch any java webstart application on a 32-bit Windows 7 system.
E.g. ArgoUML - http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp
Everything works fine with Java 6, but with Java 7 I get this kind of errors:

> Unable to load resource: **java.io.IOException: Error writing to
>   server** or **java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**

```
Java version:
Java Web Start 10.7.2.11
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
```

Here is the trace log:

```
    Log started: pe, 21 syys 2012 21:04:19 +0300
    basic: Java part started
    basic: jnlpx.jvm: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    basic: jnlpx.splashport: 52540
    basic: jnlpx.remove: true
    basic: jnlpx.heapsize: NULL,512m
    network: Loading user-defined proxy configuration ...
    network: Done.
    network: Browser is ChromeHTML
    network: Browser is IE
    network: Loading proxy configuration from Internet Explorer ...
    network: Done.
    network: Loading direct proxy configuration ...
    network: Done.
    network: Proxy Configuration: No proxy
    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.
    security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
    security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
    basic: Running JVMParams: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: -Xmx512m]
        -> [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: -Xmx512m]
    network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.07
    network: Created version ID: 1.7
    network: Created version ID: 2.2.1
    temp: new XMLParser with source:
    temp: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- JNLP File for launching ArgoUML with WebStart -->
    <jnlp
      spec="1.0+"
      codebase="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2"
      href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp">
      <information>
        <title>ArgoUML Latest Stable Release 0.34</title>
        <vendor>Tigris.org (Open Source)</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://argouml.tigris.org/"/>
        <description>ArgoUML application.
                     This is the latest stable release.
        </description>
        <description kind="short">ArgoUML 0.34</description>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo16x16.gif" width="16" height="16" />
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo32x32.gif" width="32" height="32" />
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo64x64.gif" width="64" height="64" />
        <offline-allowed/>
      </information>
      <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
      <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" max-heap-size="512m"/>

        <jar href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7-3/antlr-2.7.7-3.jar"/>
        ....
        <property name="argouml.modules"
          value=";org.argouml.state2.StateDiagramModule;org.argouml.sequence2.SequenceDiagramModule;org.argouml.activity2.ActivityDiagramModule;org.argouml.core.propertypanels.module.XmlPropertyPanelsModule;org.argouml.transformer.TransformerModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.generator.ModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.notation.NotationModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.profile.ProfileModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.reveng.CppImport;org.argouml.language.cpp.ui.SettingsTabCpp;org.argouml.language.csharp.generator.GeneratorCSharp;org.argouml.language.java.cognitive.critics.InitJavaCritics;org.argouml.language.java.generator.GeneratorJava;org.argouml.language.java.profile.ProfileJava;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.JavaImport;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.language.java.ui.JavaTools;org.argouml.language.java.ui.SettingsTabJava;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP4;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP5;org.argouml.language.sql.SqlInit;org.argouml.uml.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.uml.reveng.idl.IDLFileImport"    />
      </resources>
      <application-desc main-class="org.argouml.application.Main"/>
    </jnlp>

    temp: 

    returning ROOT as follows:

    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2" href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp">
      <information>
        <title>ArgoUML Latest Stable Release 0.34</title>
        <vendor>Tigris.org (Open Source)</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://argouml.tigris.org/"/>
        <description>ArgoUML application.
                     This is the latest stable release.
        </description>
        <description kind="short">ArgoUML 0.34</description>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo16x16.gif" width="16" height="16"/>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo32x32.gif" width="32" height="32"/>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo64x64.gif" width="64" height="64"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
      </information>
      <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
      <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" max-heap-size="512m"/>
        <jar href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7-3/antlr-2.7.7-3.jar"/>...
        <property name="argouml.modules" value=";org.argouml.state2.StateDiagramModule;org.argouml.sequence2.SequenceDiagramModule;org.argouml.activity2.ActivityDiagramModule;org.argouml.core.propertypanels.module.XmlPropertyPanelsModule;org.argouml.transformer.TransformerModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.generator.ModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.notation.NotationModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.profile.ProfileModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.reveng.CppImport;org.argouml.language.cpp.ui.SettingsTabCpp;org.argouml.language.csharp.generator.GeneratorCSharp;org.argouml.language.java.cognitive.critics.InitJavaCritics;org.argouml.language.java.generator.GeneratorJava;org.argouml.language.java.profile.ProfileJava;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.JavaImport;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.language.java.ui.JavaTools;org.argouml.language.java.ui.SettingsTabJava;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP4;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP5;org.argouml.language.sql.SqlInit;org.argouml.uml.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.uml.reveng.idl.IDLFileImport"/>
      </resources>
      <application-desc main-class="org.argouml.application.Main"/>
    </jnlp>
    temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():

    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2/" href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp">
      <information>
        <title>ArgoUML Latest Stable Release 0.34</title>
        <vendor>Tigris.org (Open Source)</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://argouml.tigris.org/"/>
        <description>ArgoUML application.
                     This is the latest stable release.
        </description>
        <description kind="short">ArgoUML 0.34</description>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo16x16.gif" height="16" width="16" kind="default"/>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo32x32.gif" height="32" width="32" kind="default"/>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo64x64.gif" height="64" width="64" kind="default"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
      </information>
      <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
      <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
      <resources>
        <java max-heap-size="536870912" version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7-3/antlr-2.7.7-3.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
        ...
        <property name="argouml.modules" value=";org.argouml.state2.StateDiagramModule;org.argouml.sequence2.SequenceDiagramModule;org.argouml.activity2.ActivityDiagramModule;org.argouml.core.propertypanels.module.XmlPropertyPanelsModule;org.argouml.transformer.TransformerModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.generator.ModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.notation.NotationModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.profile.ProfileModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.reveng.CppImport;org.argouml.language.cpp.ui.SettingsTabCpp;org.argouml.language.csharp.generator.GeneratorCSharp;org.argouml.language.java.cognitive.critics.InitJavaCritics;org.argouml.language.java.generator.GeneratorJava;org.argouml.language.java.profile.ProfileJava;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.JavaImport;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.language.java.ui.JavaTools;org.argouml.language.java.ui.SettingsTabJava;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP4;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP5;org.argouml.language.sql.SqlInit;org.argouml.uml.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.uml.reveng.idl.IDLFileImport"/>
      </resources>
      <application-desc main-class="org.argouml.application.Main"/>
    </jnlp>
    basic: new Launcher: 
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2/" href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp">
      <information>
        <title>ArgoUML Latest Stable Release 0.34</title>
        <vendor>Tigris.org (Open Source)</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://argouml.tigris.org/"/>
        <description>ArgoUML application.
                     This is the latest stable release.
        </description>
        <description kind="short">ArgoUML 0.34</description>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo16x16.gif" height="16" width="16" kind="default"/>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo32x32.gif" height="32" width="32" kind="default"/>
        <icon href="http://argouml.tigris.org/images/argologo64x64.gif" height="64" width="64" kind="default"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
      </information>
      <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
      <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
      <resources>
        <java max-heap-size="536870912" version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7-3/antlr-2.7.7-3.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
        ....
        <property name="argouml.modules" value=";org.argouml.state2.StateDiagramModule;org.argouml.sequence2.SequenceDiagramModule;org.argouml.activity2.ActivityDiagramModule;org.argouml.core.propertypanels.module.XmlPropertyPanelsModule;org.argouml.transformer.TransformerModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.generator.ModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.notation.NotationModuleCpp;org.argouml.language.cpp.profile.ProfileModule;org.argouml.language.cpp.reveng.CppImport;org.argouml.language.cpp.ui.SettingsTabCpp;org.argouml.language.csharp.generator.GeneratorCSharp;org.argouml.language.java.cognitive.critics.InitJavaCritics;org.argouml.language.java.generator.GeneratorJava;org.argouml.language.java.profile.ProfileJava;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.JavaImport;org.argouml.language.java.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.language.java.ui.JavaTools;org.argouml.language.java.ui.SettingsTabJava;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP4;org.argouml.language.php.generator.ModulePHP5;org.argouml.language.sql.SqlInit;org.argouml.uml.reveng.classfile.ClassfileImport;org.argouml.uml.reveng.idl.IDLFileImport"/>
      </resources>
      <application-desc main-class="org.argouml.application.Main"/>
    </jnlp>
    network: prepareToLaunch: offlineOnly=false
    network: Cache entry not found [url: http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp, version: null]
    network: Connecting http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting socket://argouml-downloads.tigris.org:80 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting socket://argouml-downloads.tigris.org:80 with proxy=DIRECT
    java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    network: Connecting http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting socket://argouml-downloads.tigris.org:80 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting socket://argouml-downloads.tigris.org:80 with proxy=DIRECT
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    preloader: Construct preloader delegate
    network: Connecting socket://127.0.0.1:52540 with proxy=DIRECT
    #### Java Web Start Error:
    #### Unable to load resource: http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/jws/argouml-latest-stable.jnlp
```

Comment: Have you tried this:  http://pscode.org/janela/   or this:  http://pscode.org/jws/version.html

Comment: If an application requires java 1.6+, can it be launched with java 1.7?

Comment: Yes, if I am understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Problem seems to be in Java 7 IPv6 in Windows environment.
Solution was adding:
    
    `<j2se version="1.6.10+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
    java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>`

(I also added manually java.exe and javaws.exe to exception list in Windows Firewall and F-Secure.)

Thanks to Richard Conway: http://grokkingis.blogspot.fi/2012/08/work-arounds-windows-firewall-blocking.html?showComment=1349808752760#c2225417445483685032