# java 7 jnlp is not running unable to load resource

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a windows computer with java 6 that the jnlp file works fine but with java 7 shows the following message :

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://www.pscode.org/jws/persistserv.jnlp
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I found the solution in belaz's answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535937/java-7-on-32-bit-windows-7-java-webstart-unable-to-load-resource

Comment: Good that you found it. Seems useful to me as well. +1